# AWS S3 multipart upload fails with access denied even after s3:* permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a 2 GB file which I am uploading using boto3 s3.upload_fileobj. During multipart upload PUT calls are successful but DELETE call fails with error mentioned below. I have given s3:* permission to IAM Role. Please suggest a fix or workaround for this issue.

**Error:**

*https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "DELETE"

An error occurred(Access Denied) while calling the UploadPart Operation: Access Denied*

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
extra_args = {"ServerSideEncryption" : "AES256"}
with open('filename', 'rb') as data:
    s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'mybucket', 'mykey',ExtraArgs=extra_args)
```

Please note that, for small files this code is working fine. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where does that "DELETE" message appear in the error message? Can you show us the _exact_ error it is displaying? I'm wondering why an Upload would involve a Delete operation. I doubt it would help, but you could change from `upload_fileobj()` to `upload_file()`, which does not require the `open()` command. Does your code work with small files, which would not involve multi-part uploads?

Comment: Hi John, Yes it works with small file. DELETE operations is involved because once all the parts are uploaded it combines them to create on file and delete the parts OR any interrupted part upload also needs to be deleted.

Comment: Strange! The upload process does not require parts to be deleted. The client simply calls `complete_multipart_upload()`.

Comment: Just to make sure, you use an ec2 to run the script in? If is the role that the ec2 have the same as the one you allowed to upload the files to s3?

Comment: Yes, IAM role is same.